# Android gallery intent(startActivityForResult) back button error

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I use this code and if I click button, gallery is called. However, when I click back button on gallery, `NullPointerException` occurs. How can I solve this problem? Please help me. I guess this happens because I used `startActivityForResult`, but there is no result. But I can not find how I can solve this error?

```
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_GALLERY); 
                onResume();
        }
    });
```

Comment: post stacktrace and onactivityResult code ... and y calling onresume explicitly.. post its code as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE);
```